# Add email to 17.10 Wayland Top Bar

Tags: 17.10, thunderbird

On 17.04, the top bar showed a mail icon. Clicking on it allowed me to open Thunderbird main, open a new message only or open the Thunderbird address book. I am sure there is a way but have been unable to find that in the questions or in the (Gnome ) Tweaks. How can I make that happen?

Comment: I know that 17.10 MATE has `indicator-messages`. Not sure about ordinary 17.10.  Maybe [Mailnag](https://github.com/pulb/mailnag) may trigger it via `mailnag-messagingmenu-plugin` or `gnome-shell-mailnag`.